# can't find jface

Tags: eclipse, swt, jface

I was trying to do this [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/FirstJFaceapplication.htm) and can't import the

```
import org.eclipse.jface.window.ApplicationWindow;
```

My IDE is:
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Helios Service Release 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your plugin project, find META-INF/MANIFEST.MF file and open it. You should see multi-page editor. Go to Dependencies page and add "org.eclipse.jface" under "Required Plugin-ins" section. Your plugin must declare a dependency on other plugins before types in those plugins are visible to it.

Comment: I'm not using the RCP version of Eclipse, and my project isn't plugin project.

Comment: Ok. In that case, you need to find the plugin jar that has jface library in it and add it manually to your project's build path.